# how to embed html file into xcode in the webview?

Tags: html, xcode, webview, cross-platform

Hey guys i've been working lately on developing mobile apps using html and javascript and it's going great but now i want to embedded the html file into an xcode project so i can run it on my iphone without having to use phonegape but with no luck...

```
i tried viewing some video tutorial reading some articles but not one worked with me ...
```

so can anyone tell me (in detailed step by step) how to do this.
P.S. i am new to xcode i only worked with it a couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

You can open local html file in uiwebview using xcode here is a sample which convert that file into a string and then load it into the uiwebview

```
NSString *htmlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourfilename" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Hope it will help you